# Use data in datatable to call stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I have a datatable fetching values from a stored procedure written as below:

```
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString);
sqlcon.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable("tmp");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_abc", sqlcon);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;

da.Fill(dt);
```

Now, I need to loop through the datatable and get the values of this datatable and pass it is as a parameter to my stored proc.

Comment: foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {

                    
                }
I am stuck at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe such operation is better done in the DB if possible instead of going to the DB for each row in the datatable row collection.

You can use foreach to loop through the datatable, each `DataRow` representing a row in the returned result.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     var col1 = row[0];  //access using column index/position

     var firstNameCol = row["FirstName"].ToString();  //access through column name
}
```

You can throw more light on what you want to do if it's possible to move it to DB (using stored procedure)

- [DataTable.Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx)

**Update:** Passing value to stored proc using `command.Parameters`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstNameCol);
```

Comment: How do i pass these values as a parameter to my stored proc

Comment: I have shown example of how to get each column value  in each row stored in the variables in my answer. Pass the variable to your PROC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach(object o in row.ItemArray)
    {

       //do something with o
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set parameters in a sproc:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_abc", sqlcon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@foo", "bar");
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@plugh", Integer.valueOf(17));
```

This will set the parameter "@foo" to the value "bar" and the parameter "@plugh" to the value 17. The value can be String, Integer, Boolean, probably others.

Read the documentation on the SqlParameterCollection object for other functions to set parameters. There are others that let you explicitly set the SQL data type, instead of making it guess a SQL datatype from your C# datatype. The only time I've ever needed this was when I wanted to set an Image value.

Side note that tripped me up early on: You cannot pass in NULL. If you want a value to be null, you have to pass in System.DBNull.Value. There is no doubt some good reason for this but I find it an annoying pain.

Answer (score -1):

If you only need the data to pass as a parameter to a stored procedure consider DataReader.
DataTable has overhead.
DataReader is more efficient and simpler syntax.

[SqlDataReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)

If you need the DataTable for other stuff (like bind to a DataGrid) then stay with DataTable and the answer from codingbiz +1 seems correct to me.
Servy feels strongly the answer should include how to reference a values in a DataRow.
You can do it by ordinal position or column name.

```
row[0];
row["colx"];
```

But you already have that answer from condigbiz and should give the check to codingbiz if the is what you use.

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
// Call Read before accessing data. 
while (reader.Read())
{
   if (!reader.IsDBnull(0))
   { 
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", Reader.GetString(0));
   }
}
// Call Close when done reading.
reader.Close();
```

OP commented Reader would lock table.
You could use with (no lock) or read into a List<>;
But you could also just stay with DataTable and that seems like the best plan to me.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Servy OP stated they need to get the values and pass them to a stored procedure.  DataReader is more efficient.  If they did not know how to loop a DataTable it is possible the OP is not aware of a DataReader.  If it can achieve that stated objective then I don't agree with "not and answer".

Comment: I'm not saying that's wrong in any way, and it may be much more appropriate to use a data reader.  That doesn't change that it isn't what he asked.  If you want to give the OP interesting information that may be useful, but isn't technically answering his question, you should post it as a comment, not as an answer.  If it is in an answer it need to be in addition to actually answering the question, which you haven't done.  You don't seem like a brand new user, so I'm surprised that I need to explain this to you.

Comment: @Servy But how to loop DataTable was already posted.  If it can achieve the implied objective then I would consider it an answer.  Obviously a beginning user that may have not been aware of a DataReader.  But I get your position and  appreciate that you that you explained the reason for the down vote.

Comment: If you don't think that he's even aware of the existance of `DataReader` all the more reason why this isn't an answer.  You just say *that* he should use a `DataReader`, not *how*, so you're still not actually answering his question, just providing a *comment* to nudge him in the right direction.  Again, that's not wrong, it just shouldn't be an answer; it should be a comment.

Comment: OK But cannot format a comment and I was going to give a more complete answer/comment and I got pulled away so I posted what I had.  You are a very solid member of SO and appreciate your position and will consider it in the future but I am not going to delete my comment/answer.

Comment: Well, your answer is likely to be deleted or converted to a comment by a moderator at some point, because it fits the definition of "not an answer".  The fact that you know this and refuse to fix the problem yourself is...discouraging to me.

Comment: @Blam
Using a datareader will lock my table until the looping is completed and i do not want to lock my table.

Comment: @Rashmi KR - Agreed. If the dataset will contain relatively large amounts of data (100-200 +) rows, then use DataTable, not Reader.